# How to fix "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to count the number of late arrival's (Negative numbers) in a list. After inputting the data I just get the Traceback

```
'IndexError: list index out of range'
```

The bus routes are split into 4 week's each with 5 value's (The Weekday's). The first thing the code does is add these week's together to combine one list for the the entire route. I then you a for in loop to count through each value to see if it is a minus number and then add's to a count called 'VarBUSANoLate'

```
VarBUSANoLatelist = (VarBUSA1 + VarBUSA2 + VarBUSA3 + VarBUSA4)
for Counter in VarBUSANoLatelist[0:20]:
    if VarBUSANoLatelist[Counter] < 0:
        VarBUSANoLate = VarBUSANoLate + 1
```

I should end up with the Number that were late for that group but just get this error 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: What is `len(VarBUSANoLatelist)`? (Also to fix this you could do `VarBUSANoLate = sum(1 for i in VarBUSANoLatelist if i < 0)`

Comment: Can you add the values of all the variables you mentioned in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the for-loop; your variable `Counter` contains the value, not the index of the value.
And because they are the values, the part `VarBUSANoLatelist[Counter]` will raise the error if the value happens to be greater than the number of elements in the list.

This means you can change your loop to this:

```
for v in VarBUSANoLatelist[0:20]:
    if v < 0:
        VarBUSANoLate = VarBUSANoLate + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of iterating a for loop, and you mixed both ways.

1. The first way is to use an index

   ```
   for Counter in range(20):
       if VarBUSANoLatelist[Counter] < 0:
           VarBUSANoLate = VarBUSANoLate + 1
   ```
2. The other way is to use the element in the array itself

   ```
   for Counter in VarBUSANoLatelist[0:20]:
       if Counter < 0:
           VarBUSANoLate = VarBUSANoLate + 1
   ```